# Special prompt when launching bash from within vim

Tags: linux, vim, shell

Often when I'm using vim, I want to jump to a command-line, so I do `!bash`

Almost as often, I forget whether I'm in a shell that I launched from vim or if I'm just in a shell without vim running. So I made a little script in my path called `in-vim` that runs `ps -ef | grep ^username.*vim` that tells me. However, a better way would be to affect the prompt to indicate that I'm in vim. For example, my prompt is currently:

`[username@server path]$`

but if it could say, when launched from a vim shell:

`[username@server path (vim)]$`

or something like that, it would be awesome. Any thoughts on how to make that a reality?

Answer (score 1):

I was naughty... I should have done better research before asking the question. I found something that pointed me the right direction [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html). Then I made a new file `/etc/profile.d/custom.sh` that contained this:

```
ps | grep "[0-9] vim" >/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
 PS1="[\u@\h \W] (vim) $ "
fi
```

It did the trick.